# Windows Associations - Executing Ruby Code?

Tags: ruby

Running latest Ruby in Windows 7.

I want to be able to be able to execute code from cmd by just typing code.rb
Right now I have to type ruby code.rb

Also, when I double click the code.rb file, a command prompt briefly pops up and then closes - too quick for me to read what it says.

I have tried associating .rb with ruby.exe using ftype to no avail.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Using [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/), select the checkboxes below during installation:

[image: install]

And you'll be able to do that from the command line (when in the folder, you can either type `code` or `code.rb`)

About the cmd window opening and closing really fast, I am not sure if there's a solution to that. [It doesn't seem like one exists](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000738.htm).

Comment: There is a solution to the command window: use the `.rbw` extension, which RubyInstaller associates with `rubyw.exe`. This is a special Ruby executable which does not open a command window.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a `gets` at the very end of your code, then the command window will pause until you send a return. Then it will close.

Also, if you execute the script from the command window, it will not automatically exit.